# Separate Dropdown for Day, Month and Year in Angular8

Tags: angularjs, frontend, angular8, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I need help to create custom Date Picker like the below image.

[image]

I am trying to do using formGroup But I am not much experience in angular.

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="sendMessageForm1()">
                    <select id="day" formControlName="Day">
                      <option value="">Day</option>
                      <option value="01">01</option>
                      <option value="02">02</option>
                      <option value="03">03</option>
                      <option value="04">04</option>
                    </select>

                    <select id="month" formControlName="Month">
                      <option value="">Month</option>
                      <option value="01">01</option>
                      <option value="02">02</option>
                      <option value="03">03</option>
                      <option value="04">04</option>
                    </select>

                    <select id="year" formControlName="Year">
                      <option value="">Year</option>
                      <option value="2001">2001</option>
                      <option value="2002">2002</option>
                      <option value="2003">2003</option>
                      <option value="2004">2004</option>
                    </select>

</form>
```

Help me out to complete this task.

Comment: You can create it using *ngFor, instead of those repeated lines

Comment: @EffiHol Can you elaborate in code it will helpful for me.